# peerDependency is not defined despite it being present in node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, npm-install, npm-publish

I am learning to build an NPM library. The source code for it can be found [**HERE**](https://github.com/a6kme/math/tree/0c5752a2b0e3da793a6d2d748a7a1dfb76ef232c). I have put `lodash` as peerDependency, so that the application (which uses the library) can install it themselves.

Now the problem is, that when I am installing the library (`@a6kme/math`) in an application, I am getting the error `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): lodash is not defined` on import of my library. I have checked and lodash has been installed by the application through some other library. (The `lodash` is present in the `node_modules` folder)

=== **SOME FILES FROM THE [CODE REPOSITORY](https://github.com/a6kme/math/tree/0c5752a2b0e3da793a6d2d748a7a1dfb76ef232c)** ===

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@a6kme/math",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/math.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "prepare": "npm run test",
    "posttest": "npm run build"
  },
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/a6kme/math.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "webpack-library",
    "bundling",
    "library"
  ],
  "author": "a6kme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lodash": "*"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'math.js',
    library: 'mathJs'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [/^lodash\/.+$/]
};
```

My `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I have created a [github issue](https://github.com/a6kme/math/issues/7) in the code repository.
Please give me some direction where to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was with how I was trying to build my library. The libraryTarget was not set in the `webpack.config.js`. The configuration originally was

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'math.js',
  library: 'mathJs'
}
```

While it should have been

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'math.js',
  library: 'mathJs',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  globalObject: 'this'
}
```

From the [WebPack documents](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget)

> libraryTarget: 'umd' - This exposes your library under all the module definitions, allowing it to work with CommonJS, AMD and as global variable.

Since this was my original requirement, that my library should be usable through `es6 import` or as a `script` tag in browser.

Comment: Thanks dude, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem specifically with my library not being able to find `React`, and in my case the solution was to add the following to my component:

```js
// Button.js
import React from 'react';
```

(I know this is standard practice, but I learned early on that it wasn't seemingly required, and in-project components would run and build fine without it.)